# How do I add Wikipedia as a search provider for the Safari search bar?

Tags: safari, search

In Safari, when I click on the magnifying glass in the search bar I get a menu, the bottom of which lists Google, Yahoo!, and Bing. I'd like to see Wikipedia here too, and get results returned from the Wikipedia website.

FYI, I'm using Safari 5.1 on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I just found that leaving the provider as Google and adding the word "wiki" at the end of my search terms pulls up a link to the Wikipedia page I want, much faster than menus! Not really an answer to this question so I'll leave the question up, it would be nice to get a real answer. Google just rocks!

Comment: But what about iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a plugin for Safari called Glims that lets you add different search engines (including Wikipedia) to the search bar among other tweaks. You can read about and download it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200708071107/http://www.machangout.com/).

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20170314191607/http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/safari/add-new-search-engines-to-safari-with-glims/) a post on someone's blog that details how to install it and set your search engines to what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: App looks great! FYI, no Lion support yet...

Comment: As of build 29, Glims now supports Lion.